# Add values to a group and recalculate in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to add certain values to a certain row and recalculate the values of other specific rows.

For example.  For **'aa' q222**, I would like to **add** the value **500** to the 'pwr' column. *This will then change the 'avail' values for q222 onward.*

**Data**

```
id  date    pwr     used    avail
aa  q122    1000    727.2   272.8
aa  q222    1000    975.7   24.3
aa  q322    1000    1092.7  -92.7
aa  q422    1000    1196.7  -196.7
bb  q122    1000    0       1000
bb  q222    1000    117.3   882.7
```

**Desired**

```
id  date    pwr     used    avail
aa  q122    1000    727.2   272.8
aa  q222    1500    975.7   524.3
aa  q322    1500    1092.7  407.3
aa  q422    1500    1196.7  303.3
bb  q122    1000    0       1000
bb  q222    1100    117.3   982.7
```

**Logic**

1. added **500** to the 'pwr' column for **aa q222** onward
2. added **100** to the 'pwr' column for **bb q222** onward

**Doing**

I am thinking I can index the row, but not sure exactly how to do this. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

```
df.loc[df.index['q222], 'aa'] = 500
```

Comment: Your expected data shows just changes in `avail` column, not `used`, while your description says both.

Comment: Yes I have changed/updated this. Only changes to the avail should be made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go:

```
# row q222 onward, within `id` group
mask = df['date'].eq('q222').groupby(df['id']).cumsum() >= 1

df.loc[mask, 'avail'] += df['id'].map({'aa':500, 'bb':100})
```

Output:

```
   id  date   pwr    used   avail
0  aa  q122  1000   727.2   272.8
1  aa  q222  1000   975.7   524.3
2  aa  q322  1000  1092.7   407.3
3  aa  q422  1000  1196.7   303.3
4  bb  q122  1000     0.0  1000.0
5  bb  q222  1000   117.3   982.7
```

**Note** if your `date` can be ordered as the name suggests, and the *onward* reflects the ordering, then `mask` can simply be:

```
mask = df['date'] >= 'q222'
```

Comment: ok I see you are using a dictionary, I was thinking I should use this as well to map the values. Will try this out now

Comment: @Lynn I'm not sure about your logic with `pwr` and `avail`. But You can change/update `pwr` in a similar manner.

Comment: because the new values should be added to the pwr column. ex. the value 500, should be added to rows from q222 onward for that group

Comment: Ah, I see it now, your columns are just `pwr = used + avail`, you can certainly update one column `used/avail` using that logic after update the other.

Comment: ok will do this thank you

Comment: Hi @Quang Hoang, when I use on my full dataset, for some reason it is removing the avail values from the 2nd value onward. I did this:
mask = df['date'].eq('q222').groupby(df['id']).cumsum() >= 1
df.loc[mask, 'avail'] += df['id'].map({'aa':500})  
The difference is that I changed a single id 'aa' to test it. and this phenom happened. It is deleting the other id's values from the 2nd row onward.